# how to extend log api with new function

Tags: go, logging

Im using the following code with `logrus`, and I want to extend it i.e. that 
on each usage of this logrus log it will add by default the `function` 
and the `file` but it doesn't works as

**I got**

```
{
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "info",
  "time": "2019-10-06 17:14:25"
}
```

**I want**

```
{
  "file": “myfile.go",
  "func": “myfunc:95",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "info",
  "time": "2019-10-06 17:17:53"
}
```

Im not talking about using ReportCaller: true, I just want to extend the logger with my function

How Can I do it ?

This is what I try

```
package main

import (
   "os"
   "runtime"
   "strconv"
   "strings"
   "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
   lgr().Log(logrus.InfoLevel,"info")
}

func lgr() *logrus.Logger {


   loggerImpl := &logrus.Logger{
      Out:   os.Stdout,
      Hooks: nil,
      Formatter: &logrus.JSONFormatter{
         TimestampFormat: "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
         CallerPrettyfier: func(f *runtime.Frame) (string, string) {

            pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
            if !ok {
               panic("Could not get context info for logger!")
            }
            filename := file[strings.LastIndex(file, "/")+1:] + ":" + strconv.Itoa(line)
            funcname := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
            fn := funcname[strings.LastIndex(funcname, ".")+1:]
            return filename, fn
         },


         PrettyPrint: true,
      },
      Level:        logrus.InfoLevel,
      ExitFunc:     nil,
   }
   return loggerImpl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to use `WithFields` and `logrus.Fields` like this:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    lgr().Log(logrus.InfoLevel, "info")
}

func lgr() *logrus.Entry {

    pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if !ok {
        panic("Could not get context info for logger!")
    }
    filename := file[strings.LastIndex(file, "/")+1:] + ":" + strconv.Itoa(line)
    funcname := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
    fn := funcname[strings.LastIndex(funcname, ".")+1:]

    loggerImpl := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stdout,
        Hooks: nil,
        Formatter: &logrus.JSONFormatter{
            TimestampFormat: "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            PrettyPrint:     true,
        },
        Level:    logrus.InfoLevel,
        ExitFunc: nil,
    }

    return loggerImpl.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "file":     filename,
        "function": fn,
    })
}
```

In the above code `*logrus.Entry` has all the methods you would expect from a logger. You can also use the interface `logrus.FieldLogger` but if we do so, we will need to stick to the methods on that interface, (no `Log` method for example - have to use Info / Error etc).

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    lgr().Infoln("Hello world")
}

func lgr() logrus.FieldLogger {

    pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if !ok {
        panic("Could not get context info for logger!")
    }
    filename := file[strings.LastIndex(file, "/")+1:] + ":" + strconv.Itoa(line)
    funcname := runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()
    fn := funcname[strings.LastIndex(funcname, ".")+1:]

    loggerImpl := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:   os.Stdout,
        Hooks: nil,
        Formatter: &logrus.JSONFormatter{
            TimestampFormat: "2006-01-02 15:04:05",
            PrettyPrint:     true,
        },
        Level:    logrus.InfoLevel,
        ExitFunc: nil,
    }

    return loggerImpl.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
        "file":     filename,
        "function": fn,
    })
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "file": "main.go:12",
  "function": "main",
  "level": "info",
  "msg": "Hello world",
  "time": "2019-10-07 01:24:10"
}
```